# Is $(V,+,\cdot)$ a $\mathscr F_2$ Vector space with $V = \mathscr F_2[X]/\sim$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory

happy new year!

I have some problems with an exercise about vector spaces. I have to show if the following is a vector space: $(V,+,\cdot)$ as $\mathscr F_2$ Vector space with $V = \mathscr F_2[X]/\sim$ with $f\sim g$ if there exists a polynomial $h\;\epsilon\;\mathscr F_2[X]$ so that $f-g=(X^2+X+1)h$ applies.

My thoughts on that are because $\mathscr F_2$ only consists of $\bar 1$ and $\bar 0$ there is not much to show in terms of the scalar multiplication. So what I have to show is that $(V,+)$ is an additive group. And this is the point where I am struggling. I am not quite sure what $\mathscr F_2[X]/\sim$ even means in this context. I know $f\sim g$ means a equivalence relation but I am really confused because the next exercise consist of showing that $(V,+,\cdot)$ is a field with 4 elements. But in this case it would include 1 and 0 and in my opinion $1\sim 0$ is false.

I feel like this exercise really is not that difficult. But i have some fundamental missunderstandings. So any kind of clarification is much appreciated.

Thank you very much and best regards!

Comment: What is $\mathscr F_2$?

Comment: @5xum it is supposed to be a field which consists of 2 elements. I am sorry. I don't know how to do the proper markup

Comment: The notation $F_2/ \sim$ means that you identify elements that are equivalent under your relation. So for example $(X^2+X+1)=0$ in $F_2/\sim$ because $X^2+X+1 \sim 0$.

Comment: Do you know the modulos relation for the integers? This here is basically the same but with polynomials (and over a slightly more unfamiliar field).

Comment: @Verdruss Yes I know the modulos. I have to think about it a little bit more but I think I understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\mathscr F_2[X]/\sim$ refers to the set of *equivalence classes* of the equivalence relation $\sim$.  In other words, an element of $\mathscr F_2[X]/\sim$ is a subset of $\mathscr F_2[X]$ of the form $[f]=\{g\in \mathscr F_2[X]:g\sim f\}$ for some particular $f\in\mathscr F_2[X]$.  You can think of this as a set in which the relation $\sim$ has been "turned into equality", since if $f\sim f'$ then $[f]=[f']$.

In this case, the natural way to make this an abelian group is to define $[f]+[f']=[f+f']$ (in other words, you "add" two equivalence classes by adding their representatives).  Of course, there are a lot of things you need to check.  First, you need to check that this is well-defined: in other words, if $f\sim g$ and $f'\sim g'$, then $f+f'\sim g+g'$ so that $[f+f']=[g+g']$.  You then also need to check that this operation really satisfies the abelian group axioms as well as the vector space axioms once you define scalar multiplication.